# Need some help understanding sigma

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm learning Sigma notation and I think I understand it but something confuses me.

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

If I want to find the sum of all integers when **n** is 15 then this is the same as:

$$\frac{15(15+1)}{2}$$

But, what if **i** starts at say 4. The formula above wouldn't work because it would include the iterations (incorrect term maybe?) 1,2,3.

So basically is there a formula to get the sum when **i** isn't 1?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the above formula twice: if $1\leq k\leq n$, then
$$ \sum_{i=k}^ni=\sum_{i=1}^ni-\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(k-1)k}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Think of $\sum\limits_{i=m}^n = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n - \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m -1} $

That is, cancel out the first $m$ terms of the sequence with another sum so you can still use the formula you have.

Answer (score 1):

For a generic arithmetic sequence, the sum is $$(\text{number of terms}) \cdot (\text{average of first and last terms}).$$ Notice that your formula has this format too.

The technique that establishes this is usually named after Gauss, and you can read about its derivation on [this page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) under the Sum heading.